# Efficient network search?

Tags: networking, full-text-search

I was wondering if there are any Open source projects related to high performance full-text searching over LAN networks.

Comment: What in the network is being searched?  Packets? Files on servers? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.
 So I have found what I was looking for.
DtSearch is the candidate. With the following features.

- Indexing of documents of almost any type
- Federated search across networks and drives
- Fields indexing and search
- Has powerful search and is very fast
- API that can be used for custom application development.

Which means I was looking for enterprise level data indexing and search.